# SSIS Foreach ADO Enumerator with Data Flow Task & Script

Tags: sql-server, ssis, foreach-loop-container

Been working on this all day and its driving me crazy.  I'm new to SSIS (usually a C# programmer) so things don't work the way I'd expect them to :)

(tl;dr - how can I use an ADO ForEach Enumerator and pass the whole row as variable to the Data Task (which holds a Script component) inside?)

Scenario:
I am using a CDC Splitter component in a Data Task to retrieve and split out INSERTS, UPDATES and DELETES from the CDC tables within my database.  I assign each change to a package level Object variable which is a recordset.

Taking just the INSERTS object variable I want to check for a condition on the provided string data, and if its true I want to email the change to someone.

To achieve this I dropped a ForEach container on the surface and hooked it up to the INSERTS Object variable.  Then inside that container I dropped a Data Flow Task, and then within that Data Flow Task I dropped a Script Component.

The idea is if some condition is met for the current row, the row will be added to the Script Component's Output buffer.  What's bugging me is that it seems as though the only way to achieve this is to map each column in the row to the ForEach loops variables collection.  Every example I've seen shows variables mapped starting with Index 0 etc.  However my row has a lot of columns and I don't want to create variables for every column, it seems wrong to do it this way.

So the question is.. within the ADO Enumerator ForEach container, how do I pass the current row (all the columns) to the Data Task inside (and in turn the Script Task within the Data Task) ?

Thanks for any advice...

Comment: http://www.timmitchell.net/post/2015/04/20/using-the-ssis-object-variable-as-a-data-flow-source/

Comment: I was doing this but got it a bit backwards.  I had the Data Flow inside a Foreach Loop, and the script component was in the Data Flow.

What I should have done was turn that inside out, as per the article.

Seems weird though, that I have to jump through so many hoops just to achieve essentially this statement:

`select * from AdoRecordsetObjectVariable where Gender = 'F'`

Comment: Yeah, it would be nice if a future version of SSIS lets us query object variables as though they were virtual tables.